# Keras fit() on ImageDataGenerator() with featurewise_center gives poor validation accuracy

Tags: python, keras

I have a question about  using fit() on ImageDataGenerator. 
I  run MNIST testing successfully with Dense layers , in batches.
Following code works perfectly( Validation Accuracy 98.5%).

## load

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# separate data into train and validation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split the data
valid_per = 0.15
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=valid_per, shuffle= True)

N1 = X_train.shape[0] # training size
N2 = X_test.shape[0] # test size
N3 = X_valid.shape[0] # valid size
h = X_train.shape[1]
w = X_train.shape[2]


num_pixels = h*w
# reshape N1 samples to num_pixels
#x_train = X_train.reshape(N1, num_pixels).astype('float32') # shape is now (51000,784)
#x_test = X_test.reshape(N2, num_pixels).astype('float32') # shape is now (9000,784)


y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train) #(51000,10): 10000 lables for 10 classes
y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(y_valid) #(9000,10): 9000 labels for 10 classes
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test) # (10000,10): 10000 lables for 10 classes

num_classes = y_test.shape[1]

def baseline_model():
# create model
 model = Sequential()
 # flatten input to (N1,w*h) as fit_generator expects (N1,w*h), but dont' have x,y as inputs(so cant reshape)
 model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(h,w,1)))
 model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
 # Define output layer with softmax function
 model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
 return model

model = baseline_model()
model.summary()

batch_size = 200
epochs = 20
steps_per_epoch_tr = int(N1/ batch_size) # 51000/200
steps_per_epoch_val = int(N3/batch_size) 

# reshape to be [samples][width][height][ channel] for ImageData Gnerator->datagen.flow
x_t = X_train.reshape(N1, w, h, 1).astype('float32')
x_v = X_valid.reshape(N3, w, h, 1).astype('float32')

# define data preparation
#datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,featurewise_center= True,featurewise_std_normalization=True,width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1) # scales x_t
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1) # scales x_t
#datagen.fit(x_t)
#datagen.fit(x_v)
train_gen = datagen.flow(x_t, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_gen = datagen.flow(x_v,y_valid, batch_size=batch_size)

model.fit_generator(train_gen,steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch_tr,validation_data = valid_gen,
 validation_steps = steps_per_epoch_val,epochs=epochs)
```

now, if i comment out line 53, and un-comment line 52,  54 and 55, I get validation accuracy of  1%.
so, this gives poor accuracy:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,featurewise_center= True,featurewise_std_normalization=True,width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1) # scales x_t
##datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1) # scales x_t
datagen.fit(x_t)
datagen.fit(x_v)
```

If I un-comment line 52, but keep lines 54,55 commented out, accuracy is again 98.5%,

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,featurewise_center= True,featurewise_std_normalization=True,width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1) # scales x_t
##datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1) # scales x_t
#datagen.fit(x_t)
#datagen.fit(x_v)
```

but as per Keras documentation, we need lines 54 and 55 if we use  featurewise_center.

[image]
So, I am confused what is going wrong.

Comment: Did you normalize data between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: rescale does that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've used both rescaling and feature normalization which is the cause of the problem. Don't use rescaling when doing feature_normalization. This causes all the input values to the network to be negative. Remove, 'rescale=1./255' from ImageDataGenerator.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center= True,featurewise_std_normalization=True,width_shift_range=0.1,height_shift_range=0.1) # scales x_t
datagen.fit(x_t)
```

Also, use separate ImageDataGenerators for train and validation since data augmentation is usually done only for training data. And, the mean/std is calculated on the training data and applied on the validation/test data.

Like this:

```
x_v = (x_v - datagen.mean)/(datagen.std + 1e-6)
datagen_valid = ImageDataGenerator(...)
valid_gen = datagen_valid.flow(x_v, y_valid, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: @Manoj.Thanks. apologies for late reply as I was testing the above code with variations. I think problem is using feature normalization and data augmentation both clubbed into one ImageDataGenerator.  I think we should scale train,validation and test data separately before calling Imagedatagenerator. if  doing sampling normalization, do it  on train and validation data separately. if doing  feature normalization , do it on training data,but use feature mean and sd on validation data as you showed. finally, do augmentation on training data.

Comment: Also, I tested and found that we should be fine with scaling and sample normalization done as part of ImageDatagenerator, but scaling coupled with feature normalization done as part of ImageDatagenerator does cause problems.